# Insert multiple values in MySQL with Python from an array

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to insert data from my array into MySQL.
To my big surprise there were not many examples on how to do it if you perform a for-loop for your array, every example that I have found was from an already existing array list.

Thanks to Adrian below, we noticed that I need tuples for my list.

**Updated code**

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost', 
    database='test',
    user='root', 
    password='pass'
    )

query = "INSERT INTO blue (created, published, publisher) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"

array = []
# The idea here is to get all table rows in the page so you can group the values into rows that are going to be added to MySQL
tr = soup.find_all('tr')
for table_row in tr:
    row_data = table_row.find_all('td')
    insert_row = []
    for data in row_data:
        data = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', str(data))
        insert_row.append(data)
    array.append(tuple(insert_row))
print(array)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.executemany(query, array)
cursor.commit()
```

Getting close but at the moment I receive the following

> IndexError: Tuple index out of range
>
> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is array a list of lists or just a list of strings, because it looks like you are just iterating over a list of strings and for each string are trying to do an `executemany` that is expecting 3 parameters but you only pass 1

Comment: Hmm you might  be on to something, I believe a list of strings. So it might think everything I'm iterating is one big string?

Comment: if `len(array) == 3` then you don't need a `for-loop` simply doing `cursor.execute(query, array)` should work

Comment: The array contains way more data then 3, my three columns in the DB will contain a lot of rows.

Comment: then you need `array` to be a list of list where each inner list has a length of 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing two ways of solving the problem...

One way is using the executemany method as described in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html)

```
query = "INSERT INTO blues (created, published, publisher) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"

array = []
# The idea here is to get all table rows in the page so you
# can group the values into rows that are going to be added to MySQL
tr = soup.find_all('tr')
for table_row in tr:
    row_data = table_row.find_all('td')
    insert_row = [None, None, None]
    for idx in range(len(row_data)):
        if row_data[idx] and idx < 3:
            data = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', str(row_data[idx]))
            if data:
                insert_row[idx] = data
    array.append(tuple(insert_row))

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.executemany(query, array)
cursor.commit()
```

Another way is to build the query yourself...

```
query = "INSERT INTO blues (created, published, publisher) VALUES "
array = []
# The idea here is to get all table rows in the page so you can group the values into rows that are going to be added to MySQL
tr = soup.find_all('tr')
for table_row in tr:
    row_data = table_row.find_all('td')
    insert_row = []
    for data in row_data:
        data = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', str(data))
        insert_row.append(data)
    array.append(tuple(insert_row))

values = []
for item in array:
    row = [None, None, None]
    for idx in range(len(item)):
        row[idx] = item[idx]
    values.append(str(tuple(row)))

query += ",".join(values)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.commit()
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for examples, two questions! In your example 1, you have the data from the array. But I am retrieving data from a HTML Table with beautifulSoup, so I can't "hardcode" the list, correct? I started to play around with your second example, three columns and lots of collected data under these columns should be inserted but can't get it to work. What did you mean by "Assuming there always 3 elements in each item"?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I receive is IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Okay, so...Example 1 - I put the example array so you could see what the array should look like when calling cursor.executemany(query, array). I would imagine that you don't want a hardcoded array =). If you are unsure of how your array looks you can always do a print(array) statement in your code to inspect & compare. Example 2 - What I meant by that is that when building your "array" you should make sure that every item in the array (could be a tuple as the hardcoded example on Example 1) has a value. These values are gonna be used to do the insert so make sure they are compatible with MySQL

Comment: @massideux if you could show me how your array looks like after it is built by the first loop I could edit my answer with the final solution

Comment: Thanks, took a look at my array and it seems like the way i m retrieving my data mess it all up. I will modify some bits and hopefully get back here with some progress, thanks! :)

Comment: Hi again Adrian, I have in the test code above three columns and the data in my array is in the following format: ['2020-01-03', 'Blabla', 'Red', '2020-01-03', ''Blublu', 'Red', '2020-01-03', ''Blublu', 'Red'] which I thought should create three rows. In the actual code I have more columns and more data but it's a bit to much to post here and it shouldn't matter I assume?

Comment: I see the problem, you have an array of strings, you need an array of tuples. Can you modify the way they array is built so that you get this:  [ ('2020-01-03', 'Blabla', 'Red'), ('2020-01-03', ''Blublu', 'Red'), ('2020-01-03', ''Blublu', 'Red')] ? Can you update your question with the code that builds that array you shared with me? I could help you getting the right code if you do that

Comment: I see, I added print(array) right after array.append(data).

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope it makes sense...Basically, your code was getting all table rows from the page without splitting them into groups (or rows). For this reason, you first need to look up all rows, and then for each row you need to look up the data. Once you have the data, you need to build a tuple with it, and add that tuple to the array that is gonna be used by the executemany method

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time! I assume "array" in the below should be replaced with insert_row correct? Also, table_data is not defined. Should it be insert_row?
 array.append(tuple(table_data))

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, was in a rush. I fixed the Example 1 & 2. Not sure which one you are planning on using.

Comment: We are definitely getting closer, print array looks good but I updated the original post with the error message. IndexError: tuple index out of range and  "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement", regarding cursor.executemany(query, array)

Comment: I would guess that this error happens because not all the table rows have the three pieces of information needed for the insert. Check my updated code. This solution would insert NULL values if the value in the table row is not set. I would do a print on the "array" before cursor.executemany to verify that all the tuples have 3 elements and they are all valid values.

Comment: Once again thanks for your help, this was a tricky one. It now complains about insert_row[idx = data (IndexError: list assignment index out of range).

Comment: So I would guess that that error happens because a row has more than just 3 elements. I don't know where you are pulling the data from so I cannot analyze it to do proper validation, parsing, etc. I have updated my answer so you can have a working solution that assumes the values you need are the first three "td" of each row.